# Swift JSON Parsing Issue

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse JSON, I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. Here are my classes. But I couldn't parse the JSON and assign the result to my object. The result of `print(art)` is : `[<JSONParsing.Article: 0x7fb161c28800>]`

```
import SwiftyJSON

class Article : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var articleDate : String!
    var articleId : Int!

    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        articleDate = json["article_date"].stringValue
        articleId = json["article_id"].intValue
    }
}

class articlesJSON{

    var articles : [Article]!
    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed json values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        articles = [Article]()
        let articlesArray = json["articles"].arrayValue
        for articlesJson in articlesArray{
            let value = Article(fromJson: articlesJson)
            articles.append(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Alamofire Request:

```
func loadArticle(_ start: Int, sort: String, callback: @escaping (Article) -> Void){
    let index = "articles"
    let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = ["index": index as AnyObject, "start": start as AnyObject, "size": 25 as AnyObject, "client_id": "serdar" as AnyObject, "order_filter": sort as AnyObject]
    Alamofire.request(urlLoadArticle, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

        guard response.result.error == nil else {
            // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
            print(response.result.error!)
            debugPrint(response)
            return
        }
        if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
            let art = Article.init(fromJson: JSON(value))
            print(art)
            callback(art)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surely you have done some debugging. What values do you get that are correct, and what values are wrong? What operations start with values that are correct and produce results that are wrong?